# TFS is not connecting through Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Not able to connect with TFS through Visual Studio 2012, giving below exceptions on launching "Source Control" option from Team Project...
[image]
[image]

From Activity Log i found below error:

SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.HatPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]

Answer (score 0):

Please:

1. Delete the Visual Studio Team Explorer cache via deleting the C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache folder.
2. If the first item above doesn't work, please download and reinstall Team Explorer 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656